# Do we need to show foreign asset's (US stocks) dividend in ITR filing, That even not withdrawn from the broker (US stock broker)?

Tags: stocks, income-tax, india, dividends, foreign-accounts

I have purchased foreign assets (US stocks) using the INDMoney app for about 5000 rupees from india. And I have received dividends for that stocks in US broker website. Dividends are very low and I couldn't withdraw my money. Minimum requirement for withdrawal in 1$ but dividends are below 1$, So not able to withdraw that money. So do I need to show that dividends in ITR filling, Which I couldn't even received that money in my indian bank?

Answer (score 1):

Being an Indian resident, all incomes are covered - whether Indian or foreign.
So, you need to disclose this dividend income.